# android studio button visibility

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a very simple activity which includes 1 button and that is linked to second activity.

> The problem is the button won't show up in app!

I have the button in my editor but when i create apk file there is no button in my app.

#### In App

[image: one]

#### In Editor

[image: two]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
            android:text="@string/selamatDatang"
            android:textColor="#673AB7"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.143"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.022" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
            ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="171dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="119dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="119dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="186dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="121dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="121dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="362dp"
            android:text="@string/alphabetButton" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**any idea?**

Comment: Please share your whole layout file with question

Comment: @NileshRathod updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to make your button in center in the screen then just use **`android:layout_centerInParent="true"`**

Use this

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="171dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="alphabetButton" />
```

Instead of this

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="171dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="119dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="119dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="186dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="121dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="121dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="362dp"
        android:text="@string/alphabetButton" />
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
        android:text="@string/selamatDatang"
        android:textColor="#673AB7"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:typeface="normal" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="171dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:text="@string/alphabetButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="171dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:text="@string/alphabetButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="171dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:text="@string/alphabetButton" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: no i don't want to make it center, if it works then i have other buttons to add. i just need to show it

Comment: a bit above the center there will be 3 buttons under each other

Comment: @mafortis can share your expected output with question so I can update my answer

Comment: same as your screenshot, add two more buttons under it with same distance and pull all 3 f them a bit up. so 3 of them in general will be in center of the screen

Comment: @mafortis welcome let me know if you have any query

Comment: sorry for late respond, yes it is working perfectly now except buttons n have space in between in app.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your button and it showed normally on my screen... However I used this:

`android:text="alphabetButton"`

instead of this:

`android:text="@string/alphabetButton"`

Comment: hi, I need to use string for 2 reasons: 1) avoid studio warnings 2) using translations so i really don't think using strings is the issue here. thanks btw

Answer (score -1):

**USE LINEAR LAYOUT AS PARENT LAYOUT**
i think your button is jumping to (0,0).
please use linear layout as parent layout
and then add button in linear layout..